# My first for loop

Tags: java, loops

I am studying to be a little programming. I have a for loop that sorts the months from January to December. Now I want to reverse the for loop to sort the months from December to January. Thanks for your help

```
for (int i=1; i<=12; i++){
    String month;
    if (i<10){
        month= "0"+i;
    } else {
        month= ""+i;
    }
```

Comment: for ( int i = 12; i > 0; i--)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=12; i>=1; i--) {
    String month;
    if (i<10) month= "0" + i;
    else month= "" + i;
    //You might want to do something with the variable "month"
}
```

Comment: It's best to have `if/then` blocks in braces (as in OP's original code), even if the conditionals are one line.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I've worked with both styles of code and just want to ask why.  I prefer writing if/else statements the minimalist way, braces-wise.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed before, you should reverse your loops, to count from 12 to 1. In order to simplify your code try something like this:

```
for (int i=12; i>=1; i--) {
  String month = i < 10 ? "0"+i : ""+i;
  // Do here whatever you want.
}
```

For more details check ternary operator, and Java basics doc.

Answer (score -1):

just reverse the for loop,you will be starting from the last month going back to the first month.basically any operation that you were doing will need to be reversed

```
for(int i = 12; i>12; i--){
    //do whatever here
  }
```